# Output only changed lines

Tags: linux, diff, comm

I'm trying to get `diff` to only output changed lines, not added or deleted files.

So if file 1 contains:

```
hello 1
my 2
name 3
```

and file 2 contains:

```
hello 2
my 2
earth
```

I would get output similar to:

```
< hello 1
> hello 2
```

I've searched both on Google and Stack Overflow, and found a perl script at Stack Overflow, but that doesn't output anything.

Any way this can easily be done?

Comment: how do you know `name 3` wasn't changed to `earth`?

Answer (score 1):

According to your example, I guess your question is "get diff to only output changed lines, not added or deleted **lines**." (not files). Right ?

If so, I think it's difficult to distinguish "added or deleted lines" from "changed lines".

e.g.

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

vs

```
line 1
line 2
lane 3
```

The differences of the 3rd line, is a "changed" or a "added or deleted"